# Search specific document on documentLibrary of alfresco

Tags: alfresco, alfresco-share

System can automatically find that particular document and highlight it, if this document is available on first page of pager.

### http://ZZZZZZZZZZ:10080/share/page/site/my-site/documentlibrary?file=IFTF_Ten-Year%20Forecast%20-%20Perspectives%202008_04-2008.pdf#filter=path|a.%20Secondary%20Research/Themen/01.%20Macro%20Environment/Future%20Trends.

but if i search some particular document which may be on other page, it is not position correctly.

i need way to do that? this is my link to click

```
<a target='_blank' title='${msg("label.open_folder")}' id="yui-gen112" href="/share/page/site/${item.site.shortName!''}/documentlibrary?file=${item.encodedName}#filter=path|${item.path!''}">${item.path!''}</a>
```

Comment: Need little more explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right that the file param only highlights the document if it appears on the current page - it's a client side highlight and entirely isolated from pagination controls.

It sounds like you're trying to deep link to whichever document library page a given document appears on and highlight that document. I don't think that's possible: the page the document is on may change when content gets added and deleted and may vary from user to user if they modify their individual sort order.

This may not be the answer you're looking for, but if you want to link to a specific document, then your best bet is probably to link to the Document Details page, which has the url format:

```
/share/page/site/${item.site.shortName}/document-details?nodeRef=${item.nodeRef}
```